# Unable to map query result to variable

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below code is being used many a times in the mongo shell.

```
db.CourseContent.find({Actor: a, Object: obj})
```

So, I have pushed the query results in a variable for further use. However, it seems the query is being changed or modified which cannot be used further.

OLD CODE: (THIS IS WORKING FINE)

```
var bag={}
bag.$sri=[]; bag.$idz=[]
bag.$sri =db.CourseContent.find({Actor: a, Object: obj}).map( function(sri) {return sri.StatementRefId});
bag.$idz =db.CourseContent.find({Actor: a, Object: obj}).map( function(sri) {return sri._id});
```

NEW CODE: (NOT WORKING WHEN USING VARIABLE TO STORE QUERY RESULTS) bag.$idz does not contain any value where has it succeeds in OLD CODE.

```
var bag={}
bag.$sri=[]; bag.$idz=[]
var qry = db.CourseContent.find({Actor: a, Object: obj})
bag.$sri =qry.map( function(sri) {return sri.StatementRefId});
bag.$idz = qry.map( function(sri) {return sri._id});
```

Can someone help me find where I have been doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried appending the `toArray()` method to the cursor? `var qry = db.CourseContent.find({Actor: a, Object: obj}).toArray()`

Comment: If I convert to Array, every time I need to loop through to load the elements right 
`var qry= db.CourseContent.find({Actor: "N1", Object: "JSON1"}).toArray()
for(i=0;i<qry.length;i++){
    bag.sri.push(qry[i].StatementRefId);
    bag.idz.push(qry[i]._id);
}`
Please let me know if you have any other better solution.

Comment: How are you using `bag.$sri` and `bag.$idz` ?

Comment: Those are an array of integer elements being used many a times in the script, mostly in aggregate framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) method and his companion in crime [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) return a `Cursor` which can be consumed only once. So you need to convert the query result using the [`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) method like this:

```
var qry = db.CourseContent.fin‌​d({ Actor: a, Object: obj }).toArray()
```

I suggest you use the aggregation framework to return those values:

```
db.CourseContent.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { Actor: a, Object: obj } },
    { "group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "sri": { "$push": "$StatementRefId" }, 
        "idz": { "$push": "$_id" }
    }}
])
```

The resulted `Cursor` object contains a single document. If you are in the shell, it yield that document but using some driver, you need to iterate the cursor.

Comment: If I convert to Array, every time I need to loop through to load the elements right `var qry= db.CourseContent.fin‌​d({Actor: "N1", Object: "JSON1"}).toArray() for(i=0;i<qry.length‌​;i++){ bag.sri.push(qry[i].‌​StatementRefId); bag.idz.push(qry[i].‌​_id); }` Please let me know if you have any other better solution.